# Is the Instrumentality of Mankind an alternate universe?

Tags: instrumentality-of-mankind

I’ve picked up copies of the two-volume Baen complete works of Cordwainer Smith (*When the People Fell* and *We the Underpeople*), and am reading them according to the chronology given in the charts in the backs of the books. My previous reading of Smith was not very extensive and was 35 years ago, so this is sort of like starting fresh for me.

At this point I’m up to the story “Mark Elf”, and I’m wondering whether this is a future history or an alternate universe. The story was written in 1957. It seems to depict a future in which Nazi man-killing robots decimated our species, and where some faction of Prussians gained the technology to launch people into space during World War II. Am I getting this straight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this does not seem to be an alternate history.

The manshonyaggers that menace the wild date to a much later period, 550 years after the end of the Second World War.  They were created during a later regime, as one them announces to Carlotta in "Mark Elf":  "I am the death of all men who oppose the Sixth German Reich."  This regime number is confirmed (in German) by the text on side of the machine:

> WAFFENAMT DES SECHSTEN DEUTSCHEN REICHES
>
> BURG EISENHOWER, A.D. 2495
>
> MENSCHENJAGER MARK ELF

In the Second World War, Germany was the world leader in rocketry.  (The German Werner von Braun, who had worked on the German's V2 explosive rocket was famously taken by the Americans to lead NASA's post-war rocketry program.)  So it is not so absurd to imagines German-built rocket being sent into space during the war.  (The suspended animation needed to keep the vom Acht sisters alive during their sojourns is less realistic though.)

There is also one more piece of evidence that Smith's fictional world follows real twentieth-century history of pretty closely.  The story "[No, No, Not Rogov!](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithcordwainer-nononotrogov/smithcordwainer-nononotrogov-00-h.html)" takes place mostly in the 1950s in Soviet Russia.  The author having been an international relations expert, the story offers a probably much more accurate picture of the Soviet society of the time than many works of more realistic fiction.